# Calculate $6^{1866}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{23}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Calculate $6^{1866}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{23}$

$Solution:$ Note that $1866=22\cdot 84 + 18$ then by Fermat's theorem

$$[6^{1866}]=[6^{22}]^{84}[6^{18}]=[1]^{84}[6^{18}]=[6^{18}]$$
Then $6^6=46656=2028\cdot 23 + 12$ It is true that $$[6^{1866}]=[6^6]^3=[-11]^3=[121][-11]=[72]=[3]$$

So $ 6 ^ {1866} $ is $3 $ in $ \mathbb {Z} _ {23} $, is that correct? Thank you for reading.

Comment: I didn‘t check the computations (which you can check with a calculator) but the logic is fine.

Comment: Your computations are correct

Comment: The method is correct (e.g. see the dupe), and - of course - the arithmetic can be verified with a calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct.

You could have also said $6^{1866}\equiv6^{-4}\bmod23$.

$6^{-1}\equiv4$ and $4^4=256\equiv3\bmod 23.$